# QuickFix and automatic import suggestions not working with package published with Poetry

Tags: python, python-import, python-poetry, pylance

When I install a Pypi package which I published via Poetry, I am not able to get import suggestions by VsCode. With Pycharm that works fine.

I expect it to show up here:

[Missing import suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UPcG.png)

[This is what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KTTR.png)

I have chosen the right Interpreter. It is not specific to this test repository.
You can find the sample repository here: https://pypi.org/project/fooexperiment/
I am able to manually import the modules.

I have also tried the `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` and `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths"` options.

I am using Pylance as the language server.

Any help would be much appreciated, I am not getting anywhere..

Comment: You should publish testing packages to Test PyPI instead of PyPI, for one...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn‘t aware of that site. Will keep it in mind.